# Sharepoint EditorPart not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, .net-4.5

The problem is that `apply` and `ok` buttons do not work.

well, i have some webpart that inherits `EditorPart` and has `CreateChildControls`, `ApplyChanges` and `SyncChanges` methods overrided. Well, when control is loaded, `SyncChanges` method is called. After it `CreateChildControls` is called. Everything is good until i try to save changes by clicking on `apply` and/or `ok` buttons. After click only `CreateChildControls` is called, but not  `ApplyChanges`, nor `SyncChanges`.

Well, I dunno how can I fix this behavior. Please, advice.

```
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)]
public class AllBrandsEditorWP : EditorPart
{
    private bool isApply;

    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/somepath.ascx";

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        var webPart = (AllBrands) WebPartToEdit;
        if (webPart == null) return;
        var control = (AllBrandsEditor) Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        control.ID = "allBrandsED";
        Controls.Add(control);
    }

    public override bool ApplyChanges()
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        var webPart = (AllBrands) WebPartToEdit;
        var editor = (AllBrandsEditor) FindControl("allBrandsED");
        if (editor != null)
        {
            webPart.SummaryLinkStore = string.Empty;
            webPart.SummaryLinkStore = SummaryLinksManager.SetAll(editor.SummaryLinkStore);
        }
        isApply = true;
        return true;
    }

    public override void SyncChanges()
    {
        if (isApply) return;
        var webPart = (AllBrands) WebPartToEdit;
        if (webPart == null) return;
        var control = (AllBrandsEditor) FindControl("allBrandsED");
        var store = new List<SummaryLink>();
        store.AddRange(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(webPart.SummaryLinkStore)
            ? SummaryLinksManager.GetAll(webPart.SummaryLinkStore)
            : SummaryLinksManager.GetAll(Local.ize("SummaryLinkStore")));
        control.SummaryLinkStore = store;
        control.ShowSummaryLinks();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, problem was in child webpart. It had `GridView` with `DropDownLists` with `AutoPostBack=true` that caused postbacks, and after any postback outer buttons don't work. So I rewrote inner webpart using JS-jQuery and it works fine.